# How to align ionic HTML elements horizontally

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework

i have these ionic HTML elements :

```
<ion-card-content>

<b style="font-size: 18px;"  class="ion-float-left">Mes Jolts</b>  
<ion-img src="./assets/images/jolt-coin.svg" style="height:20pt;width:20pt;" class="ion-float-right"></ion-img>        
 <b style="font-size: 35pt; color:var(--ion-color-primary); margin-right:5%;"  class="ion-float-right">53</b>                                               

 </ion-card-content>
```

i want to get these elements horizontally aligned in the same line, this is what this code results in :
[image]

Comment: Use `slot="start | end"` to align item. `<ion-item><div slot="start">your data on left<div> <div slot="end">your data on right<div></ion-item>`

Answer (score 1):

Use flexbox for your main element

```
<ion-card-content  style="width: 100% ;display: flex; justify-content: space-between; align-items: center">

<b style="font-size: 18px;"  class="ion-float-left">Mes Jolts</b>  

<div>
  <ion-img src="./assets/images/jolt-coin.svg" style="height:20pt;width:20pt;" 
  class="ion-float-right"></ion-img>        
  <b style="font-size: 35pt; color:var(--ion-color-primary); margin-right:5%;"  
  class="ion-float-right">53</b>                                               
</div>
 </ion-card-content>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @EvrenK,  i tried your code the two first elements are aligned but the ion-img floated to the top , do you have a solution for that ?

Comment: Use also flexbox in div that I added. You should add display: flex; and align-items: center; to your div